# Standardising data of irregular shape (TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

So I have an array `XsN`  of shape (590,) and I am trying to standardise the data.

This is an example of one of the 590 elements in my array:

```
print(XsN[:1])

[array([[ 0.        ,  0.27229556, -1.8033657 , ...,  0.        ,
     0.        ,  0.        ],
   [ 0.        ,  0.20665401, -1.9340569 , ...,  0.        ,
     0.        ,  0.        ],
   [ 4.        ,  0.        ,  0.04352444, ...,  0.        ,
     0.        ,  0.        ],
   ...,
   [10.        ,  0.        , -0.5655    , ...,  0.        ,
     0.        ,  0.        ],
   [10.        ,  0.        ,  0.9150001 , ...,  0.        ,
     0.        ,  0.        ],
   [10.        ,  0.        ,  1.0005    , ...,  0.        ,
     0.        ,  0.        ]], dtype=float32)]
```

I'm then reshaping it so that it has shape (590,1):

```
XsN_2 = XsN.reshape(-1,1)
```

Now when I use StandardScaler:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

standardized_data = StandardScaler().fit_transform(XsN_2)
```

I get the  error that

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

and

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I understand it tries to find a number but instead it finds an ndarray but I'm not quite sure how to standardise data of shape (590,) where each element is its own ndarray.

**Edit 1:**

Referring to this csv file: https://gofile.io/?c=YGxCWQ

Here is some code with a sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

imp = pd.read_csv('foo.csv', sep=',', header=None)
data = imp.values
print(data)

standardized_data = StandardScaler().fit_transform(data)
```

The error I get now is:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float
```

Is there any way I can standardise this data?

Comment: Please cut & paste your posted data here as *text*, not as image. Edit & update your post.

Comment: Hi George, I'm struggling to reproduce your error. Could you please create a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) This would consist of a complete section of code including (a reduced) data set that we could just copy and paste and be able reproduce the error. Thanks

Comment: Hi Patrick, I've updated the question as you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: The file foo.csv you've attached isn't in .csv format. It should contain only numbers and commas, but it contains square brackets and ...s. It looks like you saved it by redirecting the print function to file. Try using the numpy savetxt function with your original data  `np.savetxt('foo.csv', XsN, delimiter=',') `

Comment: I'm actually using `np.savetxt("foo.csv", XsN, fmt = '%s',delimiter=",")` . I know it has a pretty wierd format but that's what I got (and probably the reason I get the errors). I basically need to extract the mean and stddev of each input feature (column of Xs) and then scale each array appropriately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without access to your original data in the form of a valid .csv file it is a little difficult to debug this. From the look of what you printed it seems like XsN is a list of arrays, so you may want to loop through each in turn or convert it into an array with expanded dimensions.

Here is an example of standardizing some dummy data which I think resembles the structure of your data. Hope that helps.

```
n = 100 

# Create feature 1
mean1 = 10 
standard_dev1 = 2
col1 = np.random.normal(loc=mean1,scale=standard_dev1,size=[n,1])

# Create feature 2
mean2 = 20
standard_dev2 = 4
col2 = np.random.normal(loc=mean2,scale=standard_dev2,size=[n,1])

data = np.concatenate([col1,col2],axis=1)

print(f"means of raw data: {data.mean(axis=0)}")
>>> 
means of raw data: [10.15783287 19.82541124]


print(f"standard devations of raw data: {data.std(axis=0)}")
>>>
standard devations of raw data: [2.00049111 3.87277793]


from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

standardized_data = StandardScaler().fit_transform(data)

print(f"means of standardized data: {standardized_data.mean(axis=0)}")
>>> 
means of standardized data: [-6.92779167e-16 -1.78745907e-15]

print(f"standard devations of standardized data: {standardized_data.std(axis=0)}")
>>> 
standard devations of standardized data: [1. 1.]
```